# Put delete and patch in same page in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

```
<form action="/projects/{{$project->id}}" method="POST">
{{  method_field('DELETE') }}
{{  method_field('PATCH')  }}

{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="text" name="heroname" value="{{$project->heroname}}"><br>

<textarea name="description" cols="30" rows="10" type="text">{{$project->description}}</textarea><br>

<button type="submit">Edit Info</button>

<button type="submit">Delete data</button>

</form>
```

Whats the problem here is if i put 'PATCH' later both my buttons will update stuff and if I put 'DELETE' later both buttons delete it. So how can solve this problem so that  both buttons will do there work and not others.

Comment: The Problem is, that you have both buttons in one form. The simpelst way is to put each functionality in a separate form

Answer (score 0):

you can't have 2 method for 1 form.

but you can change it when user clicked on button.

to do that first you should handle onclick event for your buttons by following code:

```
<button onclick="changeMethod('PATCH')" type="submit">Edit Info</button>

<button onclick="changeMethod('DELETE')" type="submit">Delete data</button>
```

and add ID for your form

```
<form action="/projects/{{$project->id}}" method="POST">
```

finnaly define javasciprt function

```
<script>
    function changeMethod(methodName){
        $('#myform').find('input[name=_method]').first().val(methodName);
    }
</script>
```

this function will be called when user click on each button and change VALUE of method to proper one.

So your **full** code will be:

```
<form id="myform" action="/projects/{{$project->id}}" method="POST">
    {{  method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="heroname" value="3"><br>

    <textarea name="description" cols="30" rows="10" type="text">4</textarea><br>

    <button onclick="changeMethod('PATCH')" type="submit">Edit Info</button>

    <button onclick="changeMethod('DELETE')" type="submit">Delete data</button>

</form>
<script>
    function changeMethod(methodName){
        $('#myform').find('input[name=_method]').first().val(methodName);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two (actually three as Saman noticed) options:
**1st: use two forms**
This may be the simplest one (until it comes to layout).

```
<form action="/projects/{{$project->id}}" method="POST">
{{  method_field('DELETE') }}
{{ csrf_field() }}

<button type="submit">Delete data</button>

</form>

<form action="/projects/{{$project->id}}" method="POST">
{{  method_field('PATCH')  }}

{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="text" name="heroname" value="{{$project->heroname}}"><br>

<textarea name="description" cols="30" rows="10" type="text">{{$project->description}}</textarea><br>

<button type="submit">Edit Info</button>
</form>
```

Using some CSS you may be able to align the two buttons and make it look like one form.

**2nd: Javascript (/JQuery)**
I will use JQuery to demonstrate this.

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" action="/projects/{{$project->id}}" method="POST">

{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="text" name="heroname" value="{{$project->heroname}}"><br>

<textarea name="description" cols="30" rows="10" type="text">{{$project->description}}</textarea><br>

<button type="submit">Edit Info</button>

<button type="submit">Delete data</button>

</form>
```

**JS**

```
$("#edit-button").click(function(event) {
//I experienced that sometimes the form submits although it's not a submit button
event.preventDefault(); 

$("#form input[type=hidden]").val("PATCH");
$(form).submit();
});

$("#delete-button").click(function(event) {
//I experienced that sometimes the form submits although it's not a submit button
event.preventDefault(); 

$("#form input[type=hidden]").val("DELETE");
$(form).submit();
});
```